# select records from Foreign Key table where one item matches multiple condition

Tags: mysql

I have two tables like below. how can I select records that have values 'orange' and 'blue' in a same time.

```
+----+----------+
| ID |SECOND_ID |
+----+----------+
| 10 |    1     |
| 20 |    2     |
| 30 |    3     |
+----+----------+

+-----------+----------+
| SECOND_ID |   COLOR  |
+-----------+----------+
| 1         |  blue    |
| 1         |  orange  |
| 2         |  blue    |
| 2         |  orange  |
| 3         |  orange  |
+-----------+----------+
```

### EDIT

ok I admit that I didn't explain the problem well. first let's call the tables **`items`** for first table and **`items_color`** for second as Alex did.
these tables have one-to-many relationship where the *`SECOND_ID`* have more than one value each time. Now I want select rows that have blue and orange in a same time and It should be the row with ID = 1 and 2.
thanks for your time.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+boolean+operators&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: I did that but I got nothing

Comment: What is your desired output? The question is really unclear...

Comment: Why did you edit your question? there is nothing new in your edit. You should just fix your data and accept my answer. that's it :-)

Comment: Ok.. your answer was accepted. and tell me what should I do after not to edit and accept your answer in the future.. :)

Comment: Just be more attentive to details ;-) You know, like everybody writes in resume :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/05254/1

```
SELECT *, 
  SUM(IF(items_colors.color='blue',1,0)) as blue,
  SUM(IF(items_colors.color='orange',1,0)) as orange
FROM items
LEFT JOIN items_colors
ON items.second_id = items_colors.second_id
GROUP BY items.id
HAVING blue>0 and orange>0
```

Comment: this query only returns the row with id = 3

Comment: because only 3 has blue and orange, as you asked

Comment: actually the only one row that doesn't meet the requirement is that row(id=3).. id=3 doesn't have 'blue'

Comment: check my fiddle and my data! and check data you've posted. in your data you haven't any `id` that has blue and orange. id1 has 2 blues, id2 has 2 oranges, and id3 has only orange, so just to show some result i changed data source in my fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

There's many ways, simpliest one will be with subqueries:

```
       SELECT'second_id' FROM 'table' WHERE 'color' = 'blue' AND 'second_id' = 
      (SELECT 'second_id' FROM 'table' WHERE 'color' = 'orange')
```

But I think this is not the most optimized way

Also, you can try with an INNER JOIN (it will work like an intersection)

```
SELECT * FROM items_colors as A INNER JOIN items_colors AS B ON
   A.SECOND_ID = B.SECOND_ID AND A.color = 'blue' AND B.color = 'orange'
```

Comment: the subquery returns more than one row

Comment: You're right. I have added a new solution. Anyway, the answer from Alex works fine

Comment: It's ok and we need another join to bring first table values: